# SWT Text Box,SWT Text Box Border color

Tags: text, colors, swt, border

How to set the Border color of Text Box  using SWT API?

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that, as far as I know.  You can, however, set no border on the text field, create a new Composite where your text field is now, give it a background color and a fill layout with a 1 px margin, and then put your text field inside it.  This gives the effect of a border of whatever color you like.